# change number on rails loop based on screen size

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change the number of times the loop occurs based on screen sizes when using a mobile responsive grid.

I know it doesn't work in CSS but with the different media screen sizes, I want the loop to occur a different *x* number of times.

**Example**

When the media screen size is at a minimum of 500px, i want:

```
<% 10.times do %>
```

When the media screen size is at a minimum of 700px, i want:

```
<% 12.times do %>
```

When the media screen size is at a minimum of 900px, i want:

```
<% 15.times do %>
```

Etc...

*HTML*

```
<div class="mediaContainer pure-g">
  <% 24.times do %>
    <div class="mediaGrid">
        <img src="http://www.some-image.jpg" class="pure-img id="commercialPic" alt="">
        </img>
        <h3 class="commercialTitle">Title</h3>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
@media screen and (min-width: 35.5em){
  Only Loop 12 times
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em){
  Only Loop 15 times
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps summarize your question a little better?

Comment: Ruby cannot read the screen's size. Your best bet is to implement a javascript solution that first detects the screen size, then loads the proper number of items via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to `Wes Foster`'s comment, there are two issues you must consider:

1. Your CSS should be *precompiled*, which means you'll have to do all your looping before compilation (not at runtime). If you don't precompile it, prepare for massive performance degradation.
2. Ruby can't take input from the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) - it has to have the data passed to it either from JS or the `user_agent` (browser info). Think of Ruby as running on a totally separate computer (which it is).

--

The answer - although not directly what you want - would be to alter your CSS so that you don't need a loop.

If you're having to style individual elements, you're doing it wrong. CSS has `classes` and `ids` for a reason - you should style your `.classes` as generally as possible, only adding `#id` styling to specific elements:

```
.table_row { 
   background-color: red;
}

.table_row#yellow { 
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you want to use media-dependent widths or something, you should make them dynamic (`%`), so that you can define them once and have them adapt.

A good example for a table:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Test</td>
     <td>Test2</td>
     <td>Test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

table.table       { width: 100%; }
table.table tr td { width: 33%;  }

@media screen and (min-width: 35.5em){
  table.table tr td { width: 25%; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, definitely more clear now. Thanks.